# OpenTK Not Drawing Mac/VMWare Win7

Tags: macos, opengl, graphics, vmware, opentk

I have a Macbook Pro Summer 2011 13" 2.3GHz which has onboard graphics and I am trying to just draw simple polygons through OpenTK. Eventually I'm going to be doing more advanced drawing(waiting to get my PC built) but for now I'm developing through VMWare. I'm using OpenTK to use OpenGL in C#. Just to make sure everything was working properly I used this bit of code to draw a triangle:
http://www.opentk.com/node/2292

It clears to the color I've set, but it doesn't draw any polygons. I've run the code in Mac OSX as well and still no luck. Full 3d games (Assassins Creed 2, Dungeon Defenders, The Witcher) all draw properly, but for some reason my code does not. Everything compiles properly, I don't even get any warnings.

Can someone help me figure out why this is?
Also: I've coded with OpenTK on this same computer before and had it draw properly, nothing is set up differently from then, it just doesn't work now.

Answer (score 1):

What i've found is that there are several classes with the same name but in different namespaces. The "solution" (more of a hack) I found is to add the following lines at the beginning:

```
using GL = OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL.GL;
using EnableCap = OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL.EnableCap;
using MatrixMode = OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL.MatrixMode;
using ClearBufferMask = OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL.ClearBufferMask;
using BeginMode = OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL.BeginMode;
```

I used these to run the immediate mode example; prior to this I had the same error as you - a window opened with no graphics being displayed at all.

I know your question is not that new and I don't know if you actually found an answer but either way I still hope this helps out.